# Custom CSS for Wordpress News Page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I currently have been customising the standard 2013 theme included with Wordpress, making the standard child theme and adding to the bottom of the style.css stylesheet.

This works fine for all of my pages, however there is a case where I need a custom stylesheet 'news.css' for the News page.

I've tried adding the following code into the header.php file, just before the closing  tag, to ensure that it's not overruled by other css files.

```
    <?php
        if ( is_page( 'news' ) ) { ?>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/news.css">

    <?php } else {
    }
?>
```

The news.css file is in the child theme's root directory, and the url is www.__.com/news/ however I still can't get Wordpress to load this file when on the News page.

What would I need to do to get this stylesheet to load, only for this page?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: SOLUTION FOUND - The news page (being my posts page) had the .blog class applied to the body tag. Using .blog in the master css file, I can now specifically adjust this page's CSS! Thank goodness!

Comment: are you getting the other link tag which has default stylesheet even on news page?

Comment: Yes - style.css is working as normal. That's been duplicated into my child theme directory and added to.

Comment: My question is are you sure is_page('news') works, you need to see if it is not showing the right url or is it not going into the if block

Comment: I've checked and I believe it's the is_page('news') portion that is incorrect. It works for is_single() on any Single page, but not for the 'News' page

Comment: Do you have post type with name news or some other page/post that news as slug?

Comment: Double checked and nothing else has the slug 'news'. If it helps, the news page is my posts page.

Comment: have you pointed news as posts page from settings?

Comment: try is_post_type_archive() instead of is_page('news')

Comment: I've found the solution sathishn and added it above. More of a workaround but seems to be standard practice according to a few places I checked. Thanks for your help bud!

Comment: glad that you found it

Comment: have you created template for "news"..?

Comment: have you created template for "news"..?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already fixed the issue by using a selector in the CSS that make the rules only apply to the page you want them to (in your case the `.blog` class worked good.

This is pretty much the standard way of doing things these days.

However I just wanted to put this here for reference in case anyone needs it in the future. The function below 'enqueues' the stylesheet and is the correct way of adding additional stylesheets. This function registers and enqueues 2 new stylesheets.

```
function load_additional_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'second-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'second-style' );
    wp_register_style( 'third-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style3.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'third-style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_additional_styles' );
```

It's also possible to use conditionals within these functions so (using the question above as the example) you could do something like this

```
function load_additional_styles() {
    if ( is_page( 'news' ) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'second-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style ( 'second-style' );
        wp_register_style( 'third-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style3.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style ( 'third-style' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_additional_styles' );
```

In the above code the stylesheets will only be added when `is_page('news')` returns `true`.